# insert a taxonomy for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have been created a custom post type and create a taxonomy for it, below is the code which i used to create those:

```
//create custom post type of jobs
add_action( 'init', 'create_jobs' );
function create_jobs() {
    register_post_type( 'jobs',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'jobs',
            'singular_name' => 'Jobs',
            'add_new' => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Jobs',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Jobs',
            'new_item' => 'New Jobs',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Jobs',
            'search_items' => 'Search Jobs',
            'not_found' => 'No Jobs found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Jobs found in Trash',
            'parent' => 'Parent Jobs'
        ),

        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-visibility',
        'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}

//create a taxonomy for jobs
add_action( 'init', 'create_jobstax', 0 );
function create_jobstax() {
    register_taxonomy(
    'jobs_taxonomy_genre',
    'jobs',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Create Jobs Genre',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New jobs genre',
            'new_item_name' => "New jobs genre"
        ),

            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_tagcloud' => false,
            'hierarchical' => true          
        )
    );  
}
```

now what i want is to insert a default taxonomy for that custom post type only, example: i want to insert "latest" and "active" as a default taxonomy for the jobs custom post type, how to achieve that? currently looking for a approach around but seems found nothing to meet my needs. Any ideas, recommendations and suggestions, would love to hear. Very thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by hooking into the `save_post` action. As `save_post` is fired for every post type and on update/publish/autosave etc., you need to add a few conditionals to avoid your terms being added multiple times and/or for inappropriate post types.

You should also have a method of checking if your terms have already been added, to avoid complications - for example you manually remove 'latest' from one job, and update it, it should not be set again.

I do this by setting a `post_meta`, defining that I already added the terms.

So, alltogether, with the checks for post type, revision, and already added terms this could look something like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'f711_save_post' );
function f711_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // return on auto-save and on other post-types
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || $_POST['post_type'] != 'jobs' )
        return;

    // check if the taxonomies have already been added
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'f711_check_tax_added', true ) == 'added' )
        return;

    // insert the new terms
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array( 'latest', 'active' ), 'jobs_taxonomy_genre' );

    // set the post meta so the terms do not get added again
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'f711_check_tax_added', 'added' );
}
```